# Async WCF response lost

Tags: c#, wcf, long-polling

I am using a WCF service to apply a long polling connection between a server, hosting the WCF service and several clients. For now, i only test with one client. The method i call from the client, is async and it contains a ManualResetEvent that will get signaled from another method.

Here is the code for the async method:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginWaitNotification(Guid printServerId, List<Guid> printers ,AsyncCallback callback, object state)
{
    var notRes = new NotificationResult(callback, state, printServerId);
    lock (SyncObject)
    {
        if ((from p in ConnectedPrintServers where p.PrintServerId == printServerId select p).FirstOrDefault() == null)
            ConnectedPrintServers.Add(new PrinterHandlePair { PrintServerId = printServerId, Handle = notRes, Printers = printers });
    }
    //wait for a notification from InvokePrint
    notRes.WaitForResult();
    return notRes;
}

public string EndWaitNotification(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var myResult = result as NotificationResult;
    if (myResult == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Result was of the wrong type!");
    lock (SyncObject)
    {
        var printerPair = (from p in ConnectedPrintServers where p.PrintServerId == myResult.PrinterId select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (printerPair == null)
            return null;
        ConnectedPrintServers.Remove(printerPair);
    }
    return "test";
}
```

And here is the method for the other method, that will send the signal:

```
public PrintData InvokePrint(PrintData printData)
{
    var returnData = printData;
    if (printData == null)
        return null;
    lock(SyncObject)
    {
        //finds a printerhandlepair
        var printerPair = (from p in ConnectedPrintServers where p.Printers.Contains(printData.Printer) select p).FirstOrDefault();
        if (printerPair == null)
            return returnData;
        //notify long polling method so it returns
            ((ManualResetEvent)printerPair.Handle.AsyncWaitHandle).Set();
        return returnData;
    }
}
```

These methods run exactly as intended.I see that they all return. The problem is with the client listening.

I call WaitNotification with this code:

```
_asyncPsc = new AsyncPrintServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding { SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1900), }, new EndpointAddress(url));
var result = _asyncPsc.WaitNotification(PrintServerId, Printers.ToArray());
```

Sometimes, not everytime, i see that `_asyncPsc.WaitNotification(PrintServerId, Printers.ToArray());` is called, but never returns. And that is even when i see that EndWaitNotification returns. What could be the cause of this behavior??

I have no problems if i close w3wp.exe before running, using the Task Manager.